# How to get rid of any program's output in terminal

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lots of paths of files stored in an array.
I want the user to enter the file no (array index) of the file they want to open, so that I can open the desired file.
I am opening the file like this:-

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(arr[pos]) ;
```

The problem, is after the execution of above statement, the terminal window starts showing output from the program I have started.  foreg, if I open a file called as "abc.mp3" then the terminal window starts showing output from RythmBox, if I open a html file, it starts showing output from Google Chrome.

I have tried opening the file by creating a new thread but, it is of no use.

When I close the program which I have started, the control returns back to my application.
How can I get rid of that?

Comment: It's not quite clear what expect to happen. What sense would it make to show an html file without the UI application it is related to?

Comment: I am not talking about the UI application, I am talking about the output the application gives in terminal. Try starting google-chrome in terminal and you'll see what kind of output I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(arr[pos]) { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
```